# How to inject deployment yaml env variable in springboot application yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, environment-variables

I am trying to read the environment variable declared in deployment yaml of Kubernetes into springboot application.yaml

Below is sample in deployment.yaml

```
    spec:
      containers:
        env:
        - name: SECRET_IN
          value: dev
```

Below is sample in application.yaml

```
    innovation:
      in: ${SECRET_IN:demo}
```

But on localhost when I try to print innovation.in (@Configuration is created correctly) I am not getting "dev" in  output, it always prints *demo*, it appears the link between deployment, application yaml is not happening ,could someone please help.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation,  and seems all examples of declared env for each container image, not sure if it works to declare env vars before declaring which container name/image you want those vars to be defined in... try specifying vars per container: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/

Comment: As an update locally it will not work, on K8 though it worked

Answer (score 3):

You can store the whole `application.YAML` config file into the `config map` or `secret` and inject it with the deployment only

For example :

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: demo
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    pool:
      size:
        core: 1
        max:16
```

if your `application.properties` is something like

example:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

You can replace it with

```
jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/dbname
```

`Deployment.yaml` will be something like

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: demowebapp
        image: registry.gitlab.com/unicorn/unicornapp:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_HOST
            value: mysql-prod
```

You can save more config into the **config map** & **secret** also based on the requirement.

Read more at : https://pushbuildtestdeploy.com/spring-boot-application.properties-in-kubernetes/

Comment: I have done something similar, but still not working, is it supposed to run on localhost as well? with above configuration

Comment: Yes, ideally it should have to work locally you can set the env variblaes, or else you can also store your whole YAML file config inside the configmap & secret.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did everything right, I have a similar working setup, although without a default 'demo'.

A couple of clarification from the spring boot's standpoint that might help.

1. `application.yml` can contain placeholders that can be resolved from the environment variables indeed.
2. Make sure that this `application.yml` is not "changed" (rewritten, filtered by maven whatever) during the compilation of the spring boot application artifact.
3. The most important: **spring boot knows nothing about the k8s setup**. If the environment variable exists - it will pick it. So the same could be checked even locally - define the env. variable on your local machine and run the spring boot application.
4. The chances are that somehow when the application runs (with the user/group) the environment variables are not accessible - check it by printing the environment variables (or this specific one) right before starting the spring boot application. Or you can do it in java in the main method:

```
Map<String, String> env  = System.getenv();
env.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```